# Vaadin 24 export component to embed into another HTML page

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

In my Vaadin Flow 24 application, I have a view:

```
@Route(value = "embedded/jobables/recent")
@AnonymousAllowed
public class RecentJobablesEmbeddedView extends VerticalLayout implements HasUrlParameter<String> {
...
}
```

which is also component(extended from `VerticalLayout`).

I'd like to export this component to be able to embed it into non-Vaadin HTML page.

I created the following exporter class:

```
public class RecentJobablesEmbeddedExporter extends WebComponentExporter<RecentJobablesEmbeddedView> {

    protected RecentJobablesEmbeddedExporter(String tag) {
        super("recent-jobables-embedded-view");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureInstance(WebComponent<RecentJobablesEmbeddedView> webComponent, RecentJobablesEmbeddedView recentJobablesEmbeddedView) {

    }

}
```

Right now I'm unable to access:

```
http://localhost:8080/vaadin/web-component/recent-jobables-embedded-view.js
```

Vaadin flow application returns 404 Page Not Found.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Just to be sure: have you mapped the Vaadin servlet to /vaadin/*, since the url you are trying to access is http://localhost:8080/vaadin/web-component/recent-jobables-embedded-view.js?

Comment: Yes, correct. The default mapping with Spring Boot 3

Comment: With Spring Boot by default the Vaadin servlet is mapped to `/*`.
The `/vaadin/*` in the example may be a bit confusing, because it has nothing to do with the reserved `/VAADIN/` path used by the servlet.
If you don't have set the `vaadin.urlMapping` property in application.properties, you should probably use `http://localhost:8080/web-component/recent-jobables-embedded-view.js`

Comment: I have similar problem and not even the /web-component/tag-name.js works. Only returns "Route not available"- page. Confirmed in debugger that the WebComponentExporter constructor is never called. 

Is there something else to do when registering the exporter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebComponentExporter` implementation must have a public default constructor. In your sample code, it is `protected` and it takes an argument.

If you check the server logs, you should see a message like

```
Class RecentJobablesEmbeddedExporter has no public no-argument constructor, and won't be instantiated as a 'WebComponentExporter' by default
```